# Visualing region of integration

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, math-software

I'm not being able to visualize this region.

I don't have or know any kind of software that can graph this:

$$R = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid (-1 \le y \le 1) \wedge (y^2 \le x \le 1) \wedge (0 \le z \le x) \}.$$

I did a few drawings but I'm not convinced.

Could anyone graph this for me and tell me the used software?

Answer (score 1):

Well,  it's hard to visualize because it is -- apparently -- very arbitrary.  But I'll try to help:

Your first condition is $y$ between -1 and 1.  Imagine two planes, each parallel to the $x-z$ plane, one at $y=-1$ and one at $y=1$.

For your second condition, concentrate on the $x-y$ plane and imagine plotting $x=1$ and $y^2=x$ (or $y=x^{1/2}$).  $x$ lies in the area between these two plots.  Imagine both plots extended vertically in the $z$ direction.  That's your second condition.

Third, imagine a plane that contains the $y$ axis, and everywhere on the plane, $z=x$.  Also imagine the $xy$ plane (where $z=0$).  The volume between those two planes is your third condition.

The intersection of these volumes is your range.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This weirdo is your region, complementing [bob.sacamento's answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1975635/266711)

[image]

It was made in Wolfram Mathematica with the command:

`RegionPlot3D[-1 < y < 1 && y^2 < x < 1 && 0 < z < x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}]`

Comment: I think i did something wrong I'm trying to graph:$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{y^2}^1 \int_0^{x} \mathrm{dz\; dx\; dy}$

Comment: @JoOkuma This integral is the volume of this region by Fubini's theorem: $\int_R 1 = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{y^2}^1 \int_0^x dz dx dy$